# Pandas 'Timestamp' object is not subscriptable error

Tags: pandas, timestamp

I have a data frame and I am trying to figure our days of the week for a data set.

df['day_of_week'] = df['CMPLNT_TO_DT'].dt.day_name()

TypeError: 'Timestamp' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Here seems `df` is not DataFrame, what is `print (df)` and `print (type(df))` ?

Comment: print (df)    

       CMPLNT_TO_DT 
0        2018-03-31      
1        2018-03-31     
3        2018-03-31     
4        2018-03-31

Comment: print (type(df)).  <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Comment: And what is `print (df.columns)` ? It is not `0` ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with an incorrect assignment.

```
df['date']=pd.date_range('2021/5/9', '2021/5/14')
df['date'].dt.day_name()
```

Output:

[image]

and:

```
df = pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01T12')
df['CMPLNT_TO_DT'].dt.day_name()
```

Output:

[image]

The problem is not with the `.dt.day_name()`:

```
df = pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01T12')
df['CMPLNT_TO_DT']
```

again:

[image]

Comment: hmmm, but then why `type` is `DataFrame` ? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71463915/pandas-timestamp-object-is-not-subscriptable-error#comment126312446_71463915) for commnet under question

Comment: I think there is some error in running code. If the author runs df['CMPLNT_TO_DT'], some thing will be clear. –